# Transpile cu1 to basis gates

Tags: bell-basis

I am trying to transpile cu1 to basis gates. How would a circuit transpiled for cu1 gate end up being in basis states (u3 and cx) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit import Parameter
from qiskit.transpiler import PassManager
from qiskit.transpiler.passes import Unroller

theta = Parameter('θ')
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.cu1(theta, 0, 1)
pm = PassManager(Unroller(['u3', 'cx']))
new_circuit = pm.run(circuit)
new_circuit.draw()
```

[image]